# Does Xcode clear .app directory every time we run it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

I create a property list file in Xcode project,and write something to it, such as name and password. I use this method

```
NSLog(@"%d",[_account writeToFile:path atomically:YES]);
```

and it does return 1

```
2014-09-03 11:16:53.576 14-09-02-LoginAndRegister[2049:60b] 1
```

but next time I run in Xcode, all the data is gone. Then I try in simulator, I exit the app, then launch it, the data is still there. So I guess that the Xcode will clear the .APP directory. So how can I store data.

PS:I know how to use SQLite, but I want to use plist here

Comment: What is the file path? also are you doing clean and run or just run?

Comment: What path are you writing to? Is it one of the locations you are expected to use within the app's sandbox: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get it.
i found that when delete a song(in my project) in my APP,then i close the APP (use home,not clicking stop the simulator)and luanch it again ,the song is not there.
but if i use  command + R to run the project,i found the file is still there